# Creating walkthrough dynamically in unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to using the Unity3d framework for a project in which I have create a walkthrough. But the client want it to be dynamic.

We would be getting the final fbx file from 3DMax which when added to a particular folder a walkthrough should be created automatically. I went through the help files on Unity3D site but did not find any documentation as to how use the Unity3D framework programmatically.

Can anyone please let me know how can it be done? Even if link is provided for the resource it would help us.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/3147 (Pro only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity 3D has a built in way to load models at runtime, but this should be done using a Resources folder (`Resources.Load()`) or using a Asset Bundles (`AssetBundle.Load()`) as described here: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/LoadingResourcesatRuntime.html

These two methods are performed inside the Unity editor and your need is load any arbitrary 3D model file at runtime, for this case you will need a plugin. The only one that I know is [ObjReader](http://www.starscenesoftware.com/Utilities.html#ObjReader).

Comment: Thanks, Using Resources.load() I was able to do it. But it is just a workaround. Thinking of writing our own model parsers to import the model in Unity3D.